# What are the reasons for getting a Socket read timed out Exception in Java?

Tags: java, database, sockets, socket.io, socket-timeout-exception

What are the reasons for getting a Socket read timed out Exception in Java?

I'm gettting:

```
    ### Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
; SQL []; IO Error: Socket read timed out; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your environment, there can be many different reasons: it could be a simple network outage between your machine and the database server. But it could also be that there is a congestion on a lower level; and one layer just sits there; all connection threads taken; waiting for some other side to move ... that won't move any more.

In that sense, the unspecific answer to your unspecific question is: identify the different components that exist in your system and that need to communicate with each other in order to deliver the functionality that they are supposed to deliver. When you have that "map"; you start checking each location on that map by its own.

And hint: if you don't have such a (mental) map yet; well, welcome to the world of professional IT. When you are responsible for a complex system; you simply have to understand the different components within that system; and how they interact. And that is not something that stackoverflow can give to you; that is something that **you** have to figure yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A timeout was set by the library and yet it didn't read anything before the timeout was reached.

This could happen if the other end it is reading from stop for a long time. The library determines what counts as a long time.  I would look for any errors logged on the server it is connected to.

Answer (score 1):

refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLRecoverableException.html!

try to check

- check input parameters in

  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","username","password");

  - check database account Expiry date
  - try to restart the DataBase
  - try to retry connection
  - if still failed try with another Database dsn